# Bootstrap Carousel NextGen JavaScript Conflict

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, conflict, nextgen-gallery

I use Roots theme (based on bootstrap) to develop custom WordPress sites. I've recently started using NextGen Gallery (and Gallery PRO) to add easily manageable photo galleries.

The issue I am having is a conflict between Bootstraps Carousel Interval Speed and NextGen Gallery. When NextGen is activated, the carousel speed sets itself to the default speed.

How can I get around this javascript conflict?

Here's the carousel script for the interval speed:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#centerSlider').carousel({
        interval: 400
    })
    $('#rightSlider').carousel({
        interval: 650
    })
});
```

Here's the website I am having issues with: www.dirtyblondecocktails.com

The gallery page is where the NextGen Gallery resides.

Can see by my script above that the two carousels should move at different speeds and much slower than they currently do on the site. As soon as I deactivate the NextGen plugin, the two carousels work perfectly.

Yes, I have tried deactivating other plugins to narrow it down to this specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using any bootstrap css and required bootstrap js.

Without its not gonna work.

Bootstrap required jquery and bootstrap js to function Collapsed menu,carousal etc.

Comment: Actually, it is now... I must have accidentally removed the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` but it's back now. Please advise again. Thank you.

Comment: use inline data-interval="1000" === 1 sec. carousel interval in mili-seconds. so 1000 is 1 sec change it to ur requirement

Comment: I'm not familiar with inline data intervals. Can you show an example?

Comment: All good! I understood myself and you solved my problem. Thank you.